# How do I determine a draw in Tic Tac Toe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to figure out how to determine a draw in the game of Tic Tac Toe but can't seem to figure it out.  Anyone have any ideas how to determine a draw?

I was thinking about adding a counter that records the amount of clicks being made. Once the counter reaches 9 clicks I can check if there are any winners; if not I then declare a draw. However, I don't know how this would be coded.

```
var player1 = "X";
var player2 = "O";
let currentClass = player1;
var moves;
var j;
const winCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [6, 4, 2]
]

let cells = document.querySelectorAll(".row>div");
console.log(cells);


for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', cellClicked, { once: true })

}

function cellClicked() {
  if (currentClass == player1) {
    event.target.textContent = currentClass;
    currentClass = player2;


    if (checkWin(player1)) {
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = "X Wins!";


      for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].removeEventListener('click', cellClicked, { once: true })
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', reset)

      }

      function reset() {
        cells[i].textContent = window.location.reload(true);

      }
    }

  } else {
    currentClass == player2;
    event.target.textContent = currentClass;
    currentClass = player1;


    if (checkWin(player2)) {

      document.getElementById("o").innerHTML = "O Wins!"

      for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].removeEventListener('click', cellClicked, { once: true })
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', reset)

      }
      function reset() {
        cells[i].textContent = window.location.reload(true);
      }

    }
  }

} 


function checkWin(player) {
  return winCombos.some(v => v.every(k => cells[k].textContent == player));
}
```

Comment: Simply counting clicks won't work if I click a box that has already been selected.

Comment: @ burrito it worked, i used a counter in the addeventlistener function...the listener only allows one click 

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', cellClicked, { once: true }) 

- once true only allows one click –

Answer (score 0):

**You can create winning combination matrix.**

```
winningCombination = [
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2],
  ],
  [
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
  ],
  [
    [2, 0],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2],
  ],
  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
  ],
  [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
  ],
  [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
  ],

  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
  ],
  [
    [2, 2],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 0],
  ],
];
```

Where, each row define, `[i,j]` position of move.

```js
class TicTac {
  constructor() {
    this.mat = [
      [-1, -1, -1],
      [-1, -1, -1],
      [-1, -1, -1],
    ];
  }
  move(i, j, m) {
    m ? this.moveX([i, j]) : moveO([i, j]);
  }
  moveX([i, j]) {
    this.mat[i][j] = 1;
  }
  moveO([i, j]) {
    this.mat[i][j] = 0;
  }
  winner(move) {
    const mat = this.mat;
    for (let i = 0; i < TicTac.winningCombination.length; i++) {
      const [[x11, x12], [x21, x22], [x31, x32]] = TicTac.winningCombination[i];
      if (
        move == mat[x11][x12] &&
        mat[x11][x12] == mat[x21][x22] &&
        mat[x11][x12] == mat[x31][x32]
      ) {
        return move;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
TicTac.winningCombination = [
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2],
  ],
  [
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
  ],
  [
    [2, 0],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2],
  ],
  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
  ],
  [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
  ],
  [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
  ],

  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
  ],
  [
    [2, 2],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 0],
  ],
];
const ticTac = new TicTac();
ticTac.moveO([0, 0]);
ticTac.moveX([1, 1]);
console.log(ticTac.mat);
let hasWinner = ticTac.winner(1);
console.log(hasWinner !== -1 ? (hasWinner ? "X Wins" : "O Wins") : "NO Winner");
ticTac.moveO([0, 2]);
ticTac.moveX([1, 0]);
console.log(ticTac.mat);
ticTac.moveO([2, 1]);
ticTac.moveX([2, 2]);
console.log(ticTac.mat);
ticTac.moveO([0, 1]);
hasWinner = ticTac.winner(0);
console.log(hasWinner !== -1 ? (hasWinner ? "X Wins" : "O Wins") : "NO Winner");
```

```css
.as-console {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```